# What is happening between receiving HTML and DOM ready?

Tags: html, performance, load-time

I've spend evenings on tuning my backend code to be served faster, yet there's a gap in page loading time that am not familiar with.

Attached an image - please tell me what is happening in highlighted time (between recieving HTML and DOM ready).

What I think it is - maybe it's DOM intself generating? But why so long? Theres like 10 HTML tags in this testing page.

[image]

That's my markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <title>#</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="a, b">
    <meta name="description" content="cde">

    <meta name="geo.region" content="PL">
    <meta name="geo.placename" content="Warszawa">
    <meta name="geo.position" content="52;21">
    <meta name="ICBM" content="52, 21">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Css/_global/Style.css">

    <!--link rel="shortcut icon" href="/Gfx/_global/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/Gfx/_global/favicon.gif" type="image/x-icon"-->

</head>
<body>

    <ul id="bredcrumbs"><li>domain.com</li><li>Home Page</li></ul>
    Content

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you use javascript on your page?

Comment: Not in this exmaple, why?

Comment: Could you provide the html code?

Comment: Do you have some chrome extensions installed? I would repeat with these disabled if you do as they can do some dom manipulations stuff sometimes

Comment: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/timeline - might be of use for you

Comment: And this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9773315/blank-time-between-resource-loading-under-network-inspector

Comment: @Luke McGregor after disabling all extensions thime highlighted on image above shortend to 5ms!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser is parsing the dom (as warlock notes) but some javascript may run during this process as well. (See [JavaScript: DOM load events, execution sequence, and $(document).ready()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307929/javascript-dom-load-events-execution-sequence-and-document-ready))

As you have seen some browser plugins can essentially inject some scripts which run pre-dom load which may show up in your load times.

Answer (score 3):

The Browser is parsing HTML and creating DOM

Comment: So this time prolongs on older CPUs?

Comment: I think that "yes", but I didn't try such tests.