# Pingdom Website Speed Test - Waterfall GAP

Tags: javascript, html, css, http

On a test at http://tools.pingdom.com/ I discovered that the loading waterfall of my website has a huge gap (**see 1st screen**).

I tried removing analytics. The gap still remains, while analytics is removed from waterfall (**see 2nd screen**).
I have a lot of css. So I cleared all stylesheet but the gap still remained.

Note: all remaining .js files are in the footer.

How can there still be such a big loading gap?
What are the possible causes?

[image: pingdom screenshot]

[image: chrome screenshot without analytics]

Comment: as commented on Niv's reply: Well, I did a further testing and put the same site onto another hosting with similar specs. in that environment there is no gap but a longer waiting for the first response. in total i get very similar total loading times. does that mean that different servers flush differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Against the theory posted by Nivs, in my case at least, it were scripts running on the server. This was indicated by a faster (no gap) response on another host with the same website.

My solution for this Problem was partial caching of my Website.

Answer (score 1):

I have done some research and got to know that, the gaps are delays/intervals timings loading the files that are loaded by scripts and CSS files. As many `.js` library images or other reference in it not loaded till the `.js` file it self not loaded.

I think the below links may elaborate your idea :
[Gaps in FireBug waterfall chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991167/gaps-in-firebug-waterfall-chart?rq=1).
Also working of firebug is decribed here http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/firebug-net-panel-timings/

Comment: Well, I did a further testing and put the same site onto another hosting with similar specs. in that environment there is no gap but a longer waiting for the first response. in total i get very similar total loading times. does that mean that different servers flush differently?