# Gt Metrix time between requests

Tags: gtmetrix

[image]

The above is my sites waterfall via GT Metrix.

All seems fine but I'm curios as to why regardless of whether the site takes 0.6 second or 1.2 seconds there is always a considerable delay to the last four requests.

The last four requests in order are:

Analytics.JS
CookieConsent.JS
Favicon.ICO (Or what ever favicon type file required by browser type)
More Cookie.js

The plan is next week to integrate the js files to my core anyway but I'm just curious as to the reason for the consistent gap.

Why so much dead time between processing. Even if it takes 1.6 seconds this large gap always exists and these four are always at the end.

Comment: Hello @DCdaz , could you solve this problem ? I face same problem.

Comment: No, I did not actually, I'm still living with it. It doesn't affect render time though. But it's giving false readings in reports.

Comment: Hello @DCdaz, thanks for reply. I found the answer. It is about dom loaded time. Some .js and query functions use dom.ready event. And If dom is not ready waiting it. But there no request etc. All about dom loaded time. Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991167/gaps-in-firebug-waterfall-chart